# MVC 4 Controller not recieving http post Message

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, silverlight

i have an issue that i can't solve. I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 Application and on top of that a Silverlight App. The Silverlight App is communicating to the mvc 4 Application over Controllers.

```
    [ActionName("Notification")]
    public string PostNotification([FromBody]string notification)
    {
       // Doing some stuff here

        return response;
    }
```

This works. However currently i added a new ControllerMethod which i can't access from my Silverlight App. Actually it works when i debug the Applikation locally. But when i publish the Project to a Server it doesn't anymore.

I can't figure what the Problem is since its working for almost every Controller, but not for 2 of them. I controlled every part of these and can't figure what is wrong.

Edit: I did use Curl to Test the Controllers, which did work.

So my question is: What could cause this behavior.

Thx.

Comment: So... The code you're showing *does* work?  Can you show the code which *doesn't* work?  Where specifically does it fail?  Is the HTTP request made at all?  What is the server's response?  Is the controller method invoked in that request?  I'm afraid "it doesn't work" isn't a very helpful description of the problem.

Comment: What does your route look like? Are you hosting it in a virtual directory where maybe your relative paths are getting lost when published? What about authorization? Is the controller protected in release mode but not debug? Try writing in some Debug.WriteLine() to see what's happening when the post is being made from Silverlight. Also, is Silverlight being hosted at a different URL or port?